# How to get items from IList

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a IList, want to get items from that

my code

```
 IList rows = dgFindBatch.SelectedItems;

 string strBatchID = rows[0].ToString();
```

How to get ?

Comment: Have you included the System.LINQ namespace?  This brings in all the Extension methods that it seems you cannot see in Intellisense yet.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood you correctly, but you can try to do something like this:

```
// OfType<T> -> gives you an IEnumerable<T>
var customer = rows.OfType<Customer>().FirstOrDefault();
```

**EDIT**

In your case I believe you want to get a DataGridRow, this is the way to do it:

```
var selectedRow = dgFindBatch.SelectedItems.OfType<DataGridRow>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Let me know If I can clarify it a little bit more.

Comment: In IList i have 6 column, BatchID, Batch... From that i want BatchID

Comment: selectedRow  giving Null Value

Comment: Well is anything ... selected ? What about this -> `var row = dgTest.Items.OfType<DataGridRow>().FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: I am selecting a row in datagrid, but then SelectedRow and Row both are giving null

Answer (score 0):

```
IList rows = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    var value = row;
}
```

Is this similar to what you are after?

Answer (score -1):

using System.Linq;

then you can have like below one and many other available at your fingertips.

rows.ElementAt(int index);